# AVPlayerViewController Showing Black Screen

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

[image]

I am trying to play a video in AVplayer with below code but it's showing black screen.I also tried googling but didn't get any luck

```
let url = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")

let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url!)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

let player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: item)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

 playerController.player = player
 self.addChildViewController(playerController)
 self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
 playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
 player.play()
```

I also added plist entry for TransportSecurity.

Comment: check internet connection.this is due to internet connection or invalid url.

Comment: i run your code in sample project. Its working, video is playing

Comment: internet is working, and I am trying to implemented this in new fresh project.

Comment: yeah , try it. btw your code is OK and working on my side as well.

Comment: is this possible to attach your project

Comment: No,it's not possible

Comment: Check the logs, what does it print at runtime?

Comment: Worked on my side as well